# Count expression SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, count, expression, ssrs-expression

Trying to count all rows in a column where `column=Yes`
I have two columns in my report Accepted and rejected.

I'm trying to count the rows where accepted=Yes and do the say thing for rejected.

I've tried these:

```
=COUNT(IIF(Fields!accepted.Value="Y",1,0))
=COUNT(IIF(Fields!rejected.Value="Y",1,0))   
=COUNT(FIELDS!accepted.value="Y")
=COUNT(FIELDS!rejected.value="Y")
```

this expression is counting every row as opposed to just the ones that are `"Y"`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can do this a couple of ways:

```
SUM(IIF(Fields!accepted.Value="Y",1,0))
```

or

```
COUNT(IIF(Fields!accepted.Value="Y",1,Nothing))
```

COUNT is a count of all Rows, so even by returning 0 it will get included in the count. This is why returning *Nothing* should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. I was overthinking the count, I didn't want to sum them but that makes sense as I'm converting if its Yes to a 1

Answer (score 3):

=SUM(IIf(Fields!Doc_Type.Value = "Shipments", 1, 0), "YourDataSetName")

this worked for me with no errors. saw this on another post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use "And" Operators to check both conditions together.

```
=COUNT(IIF(Fields!accepted.Value ="Y" And Fields!rejected.value="Y",1,0))
```