# CountDistinct coming out with wrong calculation

Tags: c#, sql, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012

So I'm trying to count the amount of fields (called [Emergency]) that are both true and false to multiply by the standard price of either a regular or emergency booking.

Currently this is only working for the emergency revenue calculation(looks like this):

```
=CountDistinct(Fields!Emergency.Value = True) * 3.0
```

And lets say there are two records with the emergency field being true, since the price of an emergency booking is £3.00, it outputs as £6.00 total

While the regular revenue calculation looks like this:

```
=CountDistinct(Fields!Emergency.Value = False) * 1.5
```

The output of this with four records having the emergency field being false and the price of a regular booking being £1.50 is £3.00, while the expected output should be £6.00

I'm not sure what is causing this problem as it's my first time using SSRS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count expression SSRS Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204530/count-expression-ssrs-report)

Answer (score 1):

You are counting the distinct values of a *boolean* expression.  This takes on two values, which is why you are getting 2.

I suspect you just want to count the number of true values.  I don't know how to express this in SSRS, but in SQL, you can do:

```
sum(case when Fields!Emergency.Value = 'False' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Comment: The expression in SSRS would be `=SUM(IIF(Fields!Emergency.Value = 'False', 1, 0))`